# Do we really need ServiceFacade Design Pattern while consuming a web-service?

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns

I wanted to know if ServiceFacade Design Pattern is really required while consuming a web-service.

http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/service_facade

Any insight and code snippet would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: http://blog.xebia.com/2009/05/11/jpa-implementation-patterns-service-facades-and-data-transfers-objects/

Answer (score 1):

The aim of the facade is to provide a forward (or client) facing endpoint, which in turn provides only what is needed for communication and hide anything which is behind it to the outside world.

Having a facade will allow you to abstract your behaviour without exposing it. It will also allow you to make changes without potentially affecting the endpoint itself. That depends on the type of changes obviously, but if you have some requirements which require some change in the logic it might be possible that the actual input and output of the service remain untouched.

If you where to do away with the service facade, any changes to the code might require your clients to update the code from their end, and those who, for some reason do not update might end up with a broken system or else you would have to cater for multiple versions.

Answer (score 1):

**Service Facade design pattern is not mandatory consuming a web-service. it is required when you don't want to expose core service contract changes**.

How it works

1. You will define a core business service contract (CoreServiceContract)
2. You will define implementation for that contract (CoreServiceContractImpl)
3. You will define one service facade which is customer facing ( ServiceFacade )
   This ServiceFacade holds the reference of contract - CoreServiceContract
4. You will invoke methods defined in CoreServiceContract through ServiceFacade. CoreServiceContract holds implementation of CoreServiceContractImpl

**Advantages:**

1) The Service Facade insulates the service definition from its implementation.

2) It is the way of decoupling the Web tier from the Business tier.

3) From a transactional point of view, the business service may implement his transaction scope or be part of the current transaction.

4) The contract of the Service Facade interface is oriented to be invoked by Web tier or client software, but methods of the contract should not be invoked 
within the business implementation.

Have a look at this article for working [code](http://softwarearchitecturelessons.blogspot.in/2013/09/ejb-patterns-service-facade-example.html)